# Requiring runtime app files from a node library with webpack

Tags: node.js, webpack

I'm working on a Node.js library that's already in production, and we are implementing Webpack to use `babel-loader`. I'm using `webpack-node-externals` to leave external requires unresolved until runtime.

The thing is, at some points the library need information about the app that is using it, and so far it's bee requiring it using the following:

```
const basepath = process.cwd();
const pkg = require( path.join( basepath, 'package.json' ) );
const packageVersion = pkg.version;
```

This has been working fine so far, since `process.cwd()` resolves to the working directory of the app that is running the library. But when ebpack reaches this require, it tries to resolve it and replaces it with a `webpackMissingModule` error.

Is there a way to leave this `require` as it is until runtime? I tried using the `externals` property with no luck.